# Why is receiving shared files from other apps so difficult on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I must be going insane, but in 2022, I still can't figure out how to allow *my* iOS app to let *other* apps share X, Y or Z types of files ***to it*** (in particular STL/OBJ model files).

In other words, I go into Files app, find a .stl file, tap Share then my app shows up as a destination. Either it's simply not possible or Apple's documentation around it is extremely hard to find.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or crush my hopes and dreams?

I know of another app that can accept STL/OBJ 3D models but I have no idea how they managed to get their app to show up in the standard Share sheet.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/defining_file_and_data_types_for_your_app

Answer (score 0):

As is usual with my on Stack Overflow, I solve my problem half an hour later after posting...

The solution is the Document Types in Info using the `public.3d-content` type to denote files including STL and OBJ format. This opened the app up to the Share Sheet from other apps sharing those formats.

Then I implement the `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` method on `AppDelegate`.